# WCF DataContract serialization of read-only properties?

Tags: wcf, serialization

Whenever I use WCF, I always try to make immutable classes that end up going over the wire (i.e. parameters set in constructor, properties are read-only). However, this gets in the way of WCF serialization, which demands that all properties be Public get/set (which makes sense, because it has to deserialize them)

Even in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508661/wcf-datacontract-set-get-not-getting-executed), I see that their solution ended up making everything Public, which violates my sense of good programming. Is there any way around this? Do I have to just settle for this solution or something like popsicle immutability and be happy with it?

The other thing I tried was something like this, where I'd have a base class for everything and a derived class that made the set useless:

```
/// <summary>
/// This represents a discovered virtual-machine template that can be
/// instantiated into a RunningVirtualMachine
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
[XmlRoot("VMTemplate")]
public class VirtualMachineTemplateBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ulong SizeInBytes { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This class is the real guts of VirtualMachineTemplate that we're hiding
/// from the base class.
/// </summary>
[XmlInclude(typeof(VirtualMachineTemplateBase))]
public class VirtualMachineTemplate : VirtualMachineTemplateBase, IXmlPicklable, IEnableLogger
{
    ulong _SizeInBytes;
    public override ulong SizeInBytes {
        get { return _SizeInBytes; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use the DataContractSerializer (which is the default for WCF), you can serialize anyhting that's decorated with the `[DataMember]` attribute - even a read-only field:

```
[DataContract]
public class VirtualMachineTemplate : VirtualMachineTemplateBase, IXmlPicklable, IEnableLogger
{
    [DataMember]
    ulong _SizeInBytes;
}
```

But you need to use the DataContractSerializer - not the XML serializer. The XML serializer can ONLY serialize public properties (and it will, unless you put a [XmlIgnore] on them).

The DataContractSerializer is different:

- it doesn't need a parameter-less default constructor
- it will *only* serialize what you explicitly mark with `[DataMember]`
- but that can be anything - a field, a property, and of any visibility (private, protected, public)
- it's a bit faster than XmlSerializer, but you don't get a lot of control over the shape of the XML - you only get a say in what's included

See this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090910052246/http://www.arquitecturadesoftware.org/blogs/hugobatista/archive/2005/11/06/wcf-basics-data-contracts.aspx) and this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090131084527/http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/pages/windows-communication-foundation-tutorial-part-2-datacontract-vs-serializable.aspx) for a few more tips and tricks.

Marc

Comment: No, you still need to include the set or it fails.

Comment: You can set SerializeReadOnlyTypes to true in the DataContractSerializerSettings.

Comment: Aw, the blog post links are dead now :(

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil: Archive.org to the rescue...  _[Blog Post #1](https://web.archive.org/web/20090910052246/http://www.arquitecturadesoftware.org/blogs/hugobatista/archive/2005/11/06/wcf-basics-data-contracts.aspx)_ and _[Blog Post #2](https://web.archive.org/web/20090131084527/http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/pages/windows-communication-foundation-tutorial-part-2-datacontract-vs-serializable.aspx)_.

Comment: Thanks @InteXX - edited the answer to include those ;)

Answer (score 3):

To ensure both immutability and easy implementation at the same time add a private setter for the property to serve deserialization. A lot happens under the bonnet, but it works.